# How to specify default property values for owned entity types in Entity Framework Core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have a simple POCO type, say something like

```
public class OwnedEntity {

    public string stringProperty { get; set; }
    public decimal decimalProperty { get; set; }
    public bool boolProperty { get; set; }
    public int intProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and an actual entity with an `OwnedEntity` reference

```
public class SomeEntity {

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public OwnedEntity OwnedEntity { get; set; }
}
```

I set up the relationship like described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) using EF Core's Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder builder) {

    base.OnModelCreating (builder);

    builder.Entity<SomeEntity> ().OwnsOne (e => e.OwnedEntity);
}
```

I can't find anything on how to define default-values for all the properties of `OwnedEntity`. I tried to initialize the properties like this:

```
public class OwnedEntity {

    public string stringProperty { get; set; } = "initial"
    public decimal decimalProperty { get; set; } = -1M;
    public bool boolProperty { get; set; } = false;
    public int intProperty { get; set; } = -1;
}
```

but with no effect. Same goes with the `[DefaultValueAttribute]` (but that was to expect since it's [explicitly mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values)).

There's a bit of information on how to handle initial values for regular entities:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeOtherEntity>()
        .Property(e => e.SomeIntProperty)
        .HasDefaultValue(3);
```

But since I'm facing an Owned Entity Type, I can't access the type via `Entity<T>`.

Is there a way of doing what I'm looking for?

Some things worth mentioning:

- I have a solid amount of specific entities where most of them are using the `OwnsOne` relation
- Declaring all `OwnedEntity`-properties in a base class is not an option since not all the entities have those properties
- I`m using EF Core 2.0.3 and ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0.4

### Edit:

Originally, I wanted to have newly created `SomeEntity` instances to come with preset properties for all of the 'embedded' `SomeEntity.OwnedEntity` properties.

But looking at how my associated controller works, it all makes sense... I have the following methods for the 'Create' operation:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create () {
    return View (nameof (Create));
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create (SomeEntity model) {
    context.Add (model);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync ();

    // redirect etc.
}
```

Which means that no object is created for the `[HttGet]` overload of `Create` and all the HTML inputs linked to properties (via `asp-for`) are initially empty. Okay. So I guess the proper way of doing this is to manually create a new instance of `SomeEntity` and pass it to the `Create` view like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create () {
    return View (nameof (Create), new SomeEntity());
}
```

Is this the right approach then or are there some more things to keep in mind?

Comment: What really are you trying to accomplish? EF Core [Default Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values) has nothing to do with class property value defaults.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you understand what EF Core [Default Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values) are for, and just looking for equivalent of `Entity<T>().Property(...)` equivalent.

The owned entities are always configured for each owner type by using the `ReferenceOwnershipBuilder<TEntity,TRelatedEntity>` class methods. To access this class you either use the result of [`OwnsOne`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1.ownsone?view=efcore-2.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_EntityTypeBuilder_1_OwnsOne__1_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func__0___0___) method, or use the [`OwnsOne`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1.ownsone?view=efcore-2.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_EntityTypeBuilder_1_OwnsOne__1_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func__0___0___System_Action_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_ReferenceOwnershipBuilder__0___0___) overload taking second argument of type `Action<ReferenceOwnershipBuilder<TEntity,TRelatedEntity>>`.

For instance, using the second approach:

```
builder.Entity<SomeEntity>().OwnsOne(e => e.OwnedEntity, ob =>
{
    ob.Property(e => e.stringProperty)
        .HasDefaultValue("initial");
    ob.Property(e => e.decimalProperty)
        .HasDefaultValue(-1M);
    // etc.
});
```