# Configure Owned property in EF Core

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-2.0

EDIT: The original problem statement included only one reference to the Owned entity. But it turns out that the problem I encountered happens with multiple references to the Owned entity AND some funky fluent configuration code.  I've rewritten this problem statement to explain the details of the problem I ran into.

I started with one EF Core entity, which references an Owned entity:

```
public class InvoiceItem
{
    public SubscriptionPlanDetails SubscriptionPlan { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
public class SubscriptionPlanDetails
{
    public string PlanName { get; set; }                // Plan name
    public decimal Price { get; set; }                  // Price (USD)
}
```

When I enter the command "add-migration" in the VS Package Manager Console, scaffolder complains:

> No type was specified for the decimal column 'Price' on entity type 'SubscriptionPlanDetails'.

So I added some fluent API configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<SubscriptionPlanDetails>()
        .Property(p => p.Price)
        .HasColumnType("money");
}
```

Problem solved... or so I thought.  Then I added another entity with a reference to the same Owned entity:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public SubscriptionPlanDetails SubscriptionPlan { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
}
```

So, each account has one subscription plan (`Account.SubscriptionPlan`), and each account has multiple InvoiceItems, each of which contains all of the details of the subscription plan that was in effect at the time the invoice item was created (`Account.InvoiceItems.SubscriptionPlan`).

Now, when I try to add a migration, it complains

> No type was specified for the decimal column 'Price' on entity type 'InvoiceItem.SubscriptionPlan#SubscriptionPlanDetails'.

So I added fluent API code to configure the Owned property.  But I neglected to remove the previous code. So, my configuration code looked like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    // This should have been removed!
    builder.Entity<SubscriptionPlanDetails>()
        .Property(p => p.Price)
        .HasColumnType("money");

    builder.Entity<Account>().OwnsOne(m => m.SubscriptionPlan)
        .Property(p => p.Price)
        .HasColumnType("money");

    builder.Entity<InvoiceItem>().OwnsOne(m => m.SubscriptionPlan)
        .Property(p => p.Price)
        .HasColumnType("money");
}
```

Attempting to add a migration gets me a `NullReferenceException`.

If I comment out the offending call to `builder.Entity<SubscriptionPlanDetails>()` then it works as expected!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify default property values for owned entity types in Entity Framework Core 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803797/how-to-specify-default-property-values-for-owned-entity-types-in-entity-framewor)

Comment: The second should work. Where are you getting NRE?

Comment: I get NRE when I add-migration In VS

Comment: Thar's strange because I've tried your code and it works for me (EF Core 2.1, SqlServer)

Comment: Aha! Figured it out. The NRE happens because of some left-over configuration code (see the totally rewritten problem statement).  I was on the right track... I stumbled over an unrelated problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to override this decimal warning is to annotate the price with the following:

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

You can also use the type "money" instead of "decimal(18,2)"